# Why am I getting "Could not find or load main class ..." error in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using netbeans on windows 7. I have created my main class in the creation of the program. I have been following a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XB3in9Xqy8&feature=share&list=PLE7E8B7F4856C9B19) but for some reason I can never get it to populate the form. What am I missing here?

```
    package inventorygui;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;


public class InventoryGUI extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InventoryGUI();

    }

    public InventoryGUI() {
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();
        int xPos = (dim.width / 2) - (this.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (dim.height / 2) - (this.getHeight() / 2);

        this.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
        this.setResizable(false);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Inventory Program");

        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Inventory Program Below");
        thePanel.add(label1);
        this.add(thePanel);





        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get this error, running from netbeans.

Comment: So is it my Netbeans screwed up in some way? I get it every time. The exact error is Error: Could not find or load main class inventorygui.InventoryGUI

Comment: Are you running this particular file or trying to run the project? Try to run this as a single file and it should run. `Right-click your file -> run file`

Comment: Trying to run the project. Should I be trying to run the file instead? EDIT: Just tried to run the file and got the same error as when trying to run the project.

Comment: Yes just run the file

Comment: 1- Try and do a clean and build. 2- Make sure that `inventorygui.InventoryGUI` is the main class for NetBeans (Right click project, select "Properties", goto "Run" and double check the "Main Class" property). 3- From within the source file, try using "Shift+F6" to run the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried compile it , it works fine no errors .
Notes  :  Be sure name of project as the public class ,also the name of package should be the same of package that you have . 
Try loading netbeans with another Jave SE version .
Try loading it with Java SE 6.20  even its old, but works fine for netbeans on win7.

Comment: How do I change what it loads with? Right now I have 7 u 45 or whatever the latest is.

Comment: Close netbeans and go uninstall the jave SE 7 u 45 from control panel , and try install another one , then open netbeans again . I hope this will help you .

Comment: I compiled the new code you putted and I compiled without errors .

Comment: Interesting to note. I rebooted into Ubuntu (I dual boot for reasons like this) and it compiled and ran just fine. I don't know what the deal with Windows is, but it looks like I will continue to work in linux instead. Thanks everyone for your help tonight!

Comment: just install anotehr jdk for windows as I told you it will work !